STOMP Connection Closes Due to Missing Heartbeats Despite Frontend Showing Ping-Pongs
I'm facing a connection issue with my WebSocket setup using STOMP and ActiveMQ Artemis. The error message I receive in my logs:
Received ERROR {message=[AMQ229014: Did not receive data from /192.0.2.1:46748 within the 20000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed.]} session=rgmekuxj

Setup:

Frontend: Using SockJS and Stomp.js. I can see ping/pong exchanges in the browser console, confirming that heartbeats are being sent from the client.
Backend: Spring Boot with StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler. Configured heartbeat intervals:

public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    int sendInterval = 10000; // Send interval in milliseconds
    int receiveInterval = (int) (sendInterval * heartBeatReceiveScale);
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue")
            .setUserDestinationBroadcast("/topic/random")
            .setUserRegistryBroadcast("/topic/simp-user-registry")
            .setTcpClient(createTcpClient())
            .setSystemLogin(username)
            .setSystemPasscode(password)
            .setClientLogin(username)
            .setClientPasscode(password)
            .setSystemHeartbeatSendInterval(sendInterval) // Set heartbeat send interval
            .setSystemHeartbeatReceiveInterval(receiveInterval);
}


2024-11-29T DEBUG 40756 --- [NotificationService] [ent-scheduler-5]
o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Received CONNECTED heart-beat=[10000, 10000] session=itwv0lto

2024-11-29T DEBUG 13048 --- [NotificationService] [MessageBroker-6]
o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Forwarding SEND /topic/simp-user-registry session=_system_ application/json payload={...}

Additionally, I am using a custom ReactorNettyTcpClient for broker connections and retry logic for failovers.
Observations:

The frontend shows ping/pong exchanges in the console, indicating heartbeats are being sent.
The backend logs show that the CONNECTED frame specifies heart-beat=[10000, 10000].

Despite this, the connection closes after the TTL timeout (20 seconds).
Questions:

How can I confirm that heartbeats are being properly received on the backend?
Are there specific configurations in Artemis or Spring Boot that I need to adjust to prevent this issue?


You can activate STOMP debug logging on the broker by following the documentation. This should give you a clear indication of whether the broker is receiving (and responding to) the STOMP heart-beats.
